# Firefox debugger won't evaluate expression

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am intermittently running into a problem with the Firefox developer tools where it stops performing any evaluation of expressions. For instance, if I type an expression in the console nothing happens:

[image]

I can't work out what the cause might be. Reloading the tab doesn't fix it, but closing the tab and opening the same URL in a new tab usually does. It's 59.0.2.

Is this a known thing? Any workaround?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should check whether the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (can be opened via Ctrl+Shift+J any related error. I can't reproduce it but I assume it may be caused by a setting or an extension of your browser profile.